# How do I call a Django Rest Framework URL using namespacing?

Tags: django, namespaces, django-rest-framework

I have a `urls.py` that looks like this:

```
router = SimpleRouter()
router.register(r'meetings', MeetingViewSet, 'meetings-list')

urlpatterns = patterns('clubs.views',
    url(r'^(?P<pk>\d+)/', include(router.urls)),
    url(r'^amazon/$', AmazonView.as_view(), name="amazon"),)
```

I want to reference the `'meetings-list'` url using `reverse`, as in:

`url = reverse('meetings-list')`

but when I try this I get `NoReverseMatch: Reverse for 'MeetingViewSet' with arguments '()' and keyword arguments '{}' not found. 0 pattern(s) tried: []`

Is there a way to do this using Django Rest Framework?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

When registering views with the router, you can pass the `base_name` in as the third argument. This base name is used to generate the individual url names, which are generated as `[base_name]-list` and `[base_name]-detail`.

In your case, you are registering your viewset as

```
router.register(r'meetings', MeetingViewSet, 'meetings-list')
```

So the `base_name` is `meetings-list`, and the view names are `meetings-list-list` and `meetings-list-detail`. It sounds like you are looking for `meetings-list` and `meetings-detail`, which would require a `base_name` of `meetings`.

```
router.register(r'meetings', MeetingViewSet, 'meetings')
```

You are also using the now-deprecated `patterns` syntax for defining urls, but you are not actually using the right `url` calls that work with it. I would recommend just replacing the `patterns` and wrapping your list of urls with a standard Python list/tuple (`[]` or `()`).

This should fix your issue, and the call to `reverse` should resolve for you.

Answer (score 3):

I think this looks much better and cleaner for you:

```
router_urls = patterns(
    '',
    url(r'^meetings/$', MeetingViewSet.as_view(), 'meetings-list'),
)

urlpatterns = patterns(
    '',
    url(r'^(?P<pk>\d+)/', include(router_urls, namespace='router')),
)
```

Then, you wil do `reverse('router:meetings-list', args=(pk, ))`

I supposed that `MeetingViewSet` is a CBV

Comment: Just a heads up, Django REST Framework doesn't conform to the standard CBVs and this will trigger an error because you need to pass a dictionary into `.as_view`