# What does base_name do in Django?

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

`router.register(r'my-model/', MyModelView, base_name='MyModel')`

I don't understand what the `base_name` is for in the code above. I've read the Django doc: https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/routers/, and other Stackoverflow questions. But I still don't understand.

Answer (score 1):

The `base_name` is required by Django rest framework for registry purpose
and only if queryset is not defined in viewset.

From queryset DRF is able to read `model._meta.object_name.lower()`.

Registry of viewsets is build based on `prefix`, `viewset` and `base_name` (of model)

See https://github.com/encode/django-rest-framework/blob/master/rest_framework/routers.py#L59

Answer (score -2):

I think the [Django documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/http/urls/#naming-url-patterns)! can help you understand.
That name can be used in other part of your code to call that url/view function.

Comment: Thanks. Can you give an example of how the name can be used in other part of my code to call that url/view function?

Comment: The [question here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27488226/how-do-i-call-a-django-rest-framework-url-using-namespacing)! has some examples. Also there is a good explanation [on this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50382141/8522675)! They are using the base_name in other parts of the code to call their view.

Comment: That is not the right documentation link, or even the right library. OP is asking about the base_name parameter to the DRF router class.

Comment: I know it, that's why I said the Django documentation could help understand about the base_name, the concept is similar from the rest framework. Also I provided links for the rest framework explanation.